# Node Express mssql returns json format without serializer and name of object

Tags: sql-server, json, node.js, express, ember.js

I'm using Node express for the back-end of my application to retrieve data from a MSSQL database. I want to approach this server by another application, made with Ember. Ember DS does not know how to deal with the format returned by MSSQL.

Format returned by MSSQL is in the form:

```
[{  
    "var1": "abc",
    "var2": "def",
    "var3": 3
{ 
    ... 
}]
```

And, if understood correctly, should be in the form of:

```
{
    'modelName': [{     
        "_id": 1
        "var1": "abc",
        "var2": "def",
        "var3": 3
    },
    { 
        ... 
    }]
}
```

Hence, it misses both the name of the record (modelName) and an ID/Serial. I want to fix this within the Express server and not in the serializer of the Ember application. I can't find how to modify the JSON output of MSSQL within Express to the one Ember understands.

API endpoint looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.get('/api/data', function (req, res) {

  var sql = require("mssql");

  // config for your database
  var config = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    server: 'mssql-server',
    database: 'db'
  };

  // connect to your database
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('SELECT * [dbo].[table]',
      function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
  });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on localhost:8080...');
});
```

Help would be highly appreciated!

I'm using (and be have to stick to) MSSQL 14.

Comment: By the way, I did find this post, which deals with the same problem. Just can't find how to fix mine. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/trouble-getting-a-simple-ember-data-example-working/8867/5

Comment: Do you mean you want to expose this as an api on the express server? You should post the endpoint that will do this.

Comment: I added the code for the API endpoint @RobertMoskal

Answer (score 0):

You just need to transform your recordset into the desired format. You can iterate through your results set and add an _id to each

```
recordset = recordset.map(each=>{
     each._id = someFunction();
     return each;
 });
res.send({modelName: recordset})
```

Then add those to the modelName key of your results. You might consider using a uuid module to assign a unique id. Just **npm install uuid**. Then:

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
each._id = uuid.v4();
```

Comment: That indeed added the name of the object, is there an easy way to add a (random) _id as well?

Comment: That's a touch harder. Let me try something.